# Структура БД для новостей и закладок

Tags: база-данных

Прошу подсказать, как реализовать структуру БД. Есть следующие задачи:

1) Есть таблица с новостями (id, title, text).
2) Пользователи могут ставить like новости и добавлять новость в закладки.

Как сделать это наиболее эффективно? Первое что приходит в голову, создать таблицу, в которой будет id пользователя и какая новость добавлена в закладку.

Но каждый пользователь при заходе на сайт, будет получать к примеру 40 последних новостей, что бы поставить отметку, что данная новость уже в избранных, нужно делать 40 SELECT запросов и искать, ставил ли пользователь новость в закладки. Мне кажется это крайне неправильным решением.

UPDATE: #Novitskiy Denis Обычный запрос на выборку с лимитом `SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40`

Comment: как вы получаете список последних 40 новостей?

Comment: 1. Используйте объединение таблиц через `LEFT JOIN` 2. Или после получения соберите коллекцию id и сделайте `SELECT ... WHERE id IN(...)`. Пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типичная связь "многие ко многим". Сделать таблицу, например, такую (синтаксис для оракла, но у остальных СУБД будет плюс-минус то же самое):

```
create table user_news_likes (
  id number,        -- primary key 
  news_id number,   -- ссылка на новость (foreign key допишите самостоятельно)
  user_id number,   -- ссылка на пользователя (foreign key допишите самостоятельно)
  like number,      -- 1 - пользователь поставил лайк, 0 - не поставил
  favorite number); -- 1 - пользователь добавил в закладки, 0 - не добавил
```

Добавляйте запись в таблицу каждый раз, когда пользователь поставил лайк или добавил статью в закладки.

Соответственно, новости со статусами (лайки и закладки) можно выбрать так:

```
select news_id, sum(like) likes_count, sum(favorite) favorites_count,
       sum(case when user_id = current_user_id and like = 1 then 1 else 0 end) in_likes,
       sum(case when user_id = current_user_id and favorite = 1 then 1 else 0 end) in_favorites
  from news n
       left join user_news_likes un on un.news_id = n.news_id
```

Здесь:

- `news_id` - ID новости
- `likes_count` - общее количество лайков
- `favorites_count` - сколько раз добавили в избранное
- `in_likes` - текущий пользователь поставил лайк
- `in_favorites` - текущий пользователь добавил в избранное
- `current_user_id` - ID текущего пользователя

Остается только выбрать 40 последних новостей (способ сильно зависит от вашей СУБД), и слегка пооптимизировать быстродействие (тоже зависит от СУБД).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, совсем забыл про JOIN, надо подтянуть знания в sql.